# Is loading bitmap from static method is memory efficient?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I would like to know whether the way I load bitmaps is efficient and can be used multiple times for constant loading and unloading of bitmaps.

I load bitmaps from assets folder using a static helper method so:

```
public static Bitmap assetImage(AssetManager am , String file){
        InputStream stream = null;
        try{
            stream = am.open(file);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            if(stream != null){
                stream.close();
            }
            return bmp;
        }
        catch(IOException e){

            return null;
        }
    }
```

I store it in a class (lets call it Sprite). now when I load or I don't need the bitmap anymore I'm recycling it and nulling. and then use the helper static method again.
My question is, will this code help me to avoid OOM errors and will garbage collect the unneeded resources?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Trying to optimize too soon is always a bad idea.

This method could prevent such problem if you where loading tons of pictures, but if you don't get that error a better approach could be to load all images and store them for future use, so that you don't need to do IO operations so many times.

Also, if you are targeting Java 7, use try-with-resources, so you won't need to close the stream: it is closed automatically.

Finally, instead of returning null if the image is not loaded, is better to return a default one (that you already have in memory), so you avoid null checks. See [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) in wikipedia.

Comment: Well, If I load too many images into memory I will run into OOM exception. That's why I'm asking if the approach that I've mentioned will free the unneeded images from the memory